# Asp.net calendar - own text on day hover

Tags: asp.net, calendar

How can I add on hover event in calendar own text, simple message what happens on that day?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips for styling the `ASP.NET Calendar`(inclusive `onmouseover-style`), found [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jhermiz/archive/2007/12/10/Cool-Tricks-With-The-ASP.net-Calendar.aspx):

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs) Handles Calendar1.DayRender
 Dim onmouseoverStyle As String = "this.style.backgroundColor='#D4EDFF'"
 Dim onmouseoutStyle As String = "this.style.backgroundColor='@BackColor'"
 Dim rowBackColor As String = String.Empty

 e.Cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", onmouseoverStyle)
 e.Cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", onmouseoutStyle.Replace("@BackColor", rowBackColor))

 If Not e.Day.IsWeekend Then
    e.Cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", onmouseoverStyle)
    e.Cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", onmouseoutStyle.Replace("@BackColor", rowBackColor))
 End If
```

You could for example use [jQuery](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/) to show a tooltip `onmouseover`.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html